# Not Able to download .apk on Android handset from our site

Tags: android

When i start downloading .apk on mobile handset(Google Nexus) from our site,following thing happens:

1.I get redirection link which is in the code
2.Start downloading the application but after download gets complete ,i get error download not completed(failed)
3. I get error page, saying page is not available,where as i an able to access net

here is the format of link to down load:/game.do?x=&y=&z=

Earlier i was able to download applications with  same code.
.

If you have any idea about the problem please let me know.

Thanks

Rakesh
.apk size varies from 500KB to 5MB

Answer (score 0):

Use below Code for download apk file from server

```
private void download(){
    try {
        URL url = new URL("url from apk file is to be downloaded");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();

        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(sdcard, "filename.ext");

        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0;

        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        } 
        fileOutput.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And Refer below link for download and install apk file from url.

[Download & Install APK File](http://lovingandroid.blogspot.in/2011/10/download-and-install-app.html)

Comment: I am using following Code:response.setContentType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
         response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
           "attachment; filename=\"" + gameName
             + downLoadFileType + "\"");
         
         FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);// File if complete path of file
         response.setContentLength(in.available());
         byte[] byteArray = new byte[in.available()];
         in.read(byteArray);
         op.write(byteArray);
         in.close();

Comment: @user1220376 you are using above code for download apk file, is it ok?

Comment: Yes,same code I am using.Also Earlier i have even downloaded the .apks.